# How can I duplicate an App?

Tags: android

I have an app and want to duplicate it (new namespace), so this
App can be installed 2x on the same device.
(In the future the 2 apps should be developed separately, only to understand)
What is the best way to do this with Android Studio?
Are there any features in Android Studio?

Comment: You have to use different package name for both the apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change your packagename. Lets say you first have the name `com.app.first` then your other application can have `com.app.second` ?

Make sure to change the packagename in your manifest aswell.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Android Studio but with the build automation tool you are using, which is gradle i assume. You dont need to change the namespace, just the appId. You can achieve this by using Product Flavors.

Check this chapter from the android documentation [Configure Product Flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors)

Comment: Now i get why ppl think that participating in stackoverflow is stupid. Thank you.

Comment: Time and time I post comments to ask people to put a comment whenever they down-vote something, it helps the author to improve their contribution.
Apologies for your bad experience @cottontree

Comment: Thank you for your kind words! But i guess im done with trying to help people.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in app build.gradle inside productFlavors block:

```
productFlavors {
    projecta{
        applicationId "com.blahblah.projecta"
    }

    projectb{
        applicationId "com.blahblah.projectb"
    }
}
```

Then you can choose the desired option before compiling in Build Variants panel.

Check this [guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html#change_the_application_id_for_build_variants) for more details.